# delete rows from a table that are not present in another

Tags: postgresql-9.1, delete-row

I have two tables

table1- ---
file_id ,est_edit_id,cal_head_code,cal_spec_code,cal_item_head_code

table 2--
file_id ,est_edit_id,cal_head_code,cal_spec_code,cal_item_head_code,cal_item_code

i want to delete rows from table 2 that does not match  values( file_id ,est_edit_id,cal_head_code,cal_spec_code,cal_item_head_code)  in table 1

any help on the same

eg
table A contains

```
-----------
file_id |est_edit_id,| cal_head_code| cal_spec_code| cal_item_head_code     
  1     |      2     |      3        |     4        |         5
--
```

### table B contains

```
file_id   |est_edit_id ,| cal_head_code  | cal_spec_code  |   cal_item_head_code  |cal_item_code   
  1     |      2     |      3        |     4        |         5          | 20
  1     |      2     |      3        |     4        |         5          | 50
  7     |      8     |      9        |     10       |         11         |21
```

i want to delete row containg value 7     |      8     |      9        |     10        |         11   from table B because 7     |      8     |      9        |     10        |         11   is not present in table A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
delete from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t1.file_id = t2.file_id
                    and t1.est_edit_id = t2.est_edit_id
                    and t1.cal_head_code = t2.cal_head_code
                    and t1.cal_spec_code = t2.cal_spec_code);
```

This assumes that none of the columns contain `null` values.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e9e9b/1